# ViewDidDisappear works fine in simulator but not in device

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

i'm working on mvvmcross for iOS and i'm facing a problem. ViewDidDisappear work fine in simulator but not in a device.
I have to use it to unsubscribe from IMvxMessenger after subscribing in ViewDidLoad, please help, thanks

First of all, i have to thinks for your intervention.
[@Stuard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373321/stuart)
- it's not craching so there is no exceptions.
- Im using MvxViewController
[@Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930789/alexey)
 - it is pushed by UINavigationController
i did juste an override on ViewDidDisappear and a breakPoint on it but never enter on it.
By the way, notice that ViewDidDisappearCalled return true.

Comment: If you include relevant parts of your code, and a better description than "not in a device" then that might help people answer you. Does it crash? Is there an exception? What versions are you running? What type of ViewController class is this in? Please edit your question to provide **much** more information - then people can try to help.

Comment: How do you present your view? Is it pushed on UINavigationController? Do you switch the Root View?